# How to count 30 days of messages with groupdate?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to use groupdate to count messages from a specific user for the last 30 days.

This seams to count all the messages instead of the 30 days. Can someone see what I'm doing wrong?

```
  @individual_messages = Message.where("user_id = ?",current_user.id)
  @chart_indiv_mess = @individual_messages.group_by_day(:created_at, range: 4.week.ago.midnight..Time.now, format: "%a, %b %e").count
```

I'm displaying the value then turning around and using chartkick to display the messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this way to show data for chartkick

```
@data_for_chart = current_user.messages.group_by_month(:created_at, format: "%b %Y").count.map { |k,v| [k, v]}
```

inside your view that showing chart (chartkick) you can do like this below

```
<%= column_chart @data_for_chart %>
```

Comment: That does help a bit. I only want to display 30 days of messages but I also want to display them individually instead of as one block so in theory it would have 30 bars. thoughts?